# Modifying XML Files in Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm pretty new to Python. I have a need to modify an existing XML file\

```
<root>
   <child1></child1>
   <child2></child2>
</root>
```

I need to add 
after child2. The content will come from a text file for newchild
For Eg:
thiscamefromtextfile

after script

```
    <root>
       <child1></child1>
       <child2></child2>
       <newchild>thiscamefromtextfile</newchild>
    </root>
```

How do I do this ? 
Thanks

Comment: What did you try and which part of the [XML Processing Modules](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.html) do you have problems with?

Comment: xml.etree.ElementTree is what I'm using. How do I achieve my task using this ?

Comment: How to add data/text to ET.Subelement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a child to an existing node use [append()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# get the root element
tree = ET.parse('some.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

elem = ET.Element('newchild')
elem.text = 'thiscamefromtextfile'
root.append(elem) # append to root or any other node, as you want

tree.write('some.xml')
```

After this when you check your `some.xml` file you will have the new node after `child2`

**Output**:

```
<root>
   <child1 />
   <child2 />
   <newchild>thiscamefromtextfile</newchild>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

data = """<root>
   <child1></child1>
   <child2></child2>
</root>"""

root = et.fromstring(data)

# create the new element and set the text
element = et.Element('newchild')
element.text = 'thiscamefromtextfile'

# add the element to the root node
root.append(element)

print(et.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))
```

An alternative way would look like this.

```
root = et.fromstring(data)
element = et.SubElement(root, 'newchild')
element.text = 'thiscamefromtextfile'
```

The result looks like this.

```
<root>
   <child1 />
   <child2 />
<newchild>thiscamefromtextfile</newchild></root>
```